# Throwing a const char* in a Try-Catch block

Tags: c++, string, try-catch

In my code I want to throw a message, so it appears in screen when an input is spotted. I wanted to do this way, but it did not work. So, I would like your help to see if is there anything that I don't know, or if it is an illegal action in C++.

This is where in my code the throw appears (a class function-member implementation)

```
//set the value of _s (seconds)
void Time::setSeconds(int s){
    if (s > 60 || s < 0)
        throw ("The value inside seconds has to be valid");
    else
        _s = s;
}
```

And this is how I manage to make a simple try-catch block

```
try{
    Time t(12,4,-12);

    t.printStandard();

    }catch(string const &a){
        cerr << a;
    }
```

However, when the program is run, I get the following error message:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'char const*'
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Which is obviously not the intended.

Comment: If you are throwing a `const char*` what are you catching a `std::string`?

Comment: Conversions are not considered for exception catching.

Comment: The claim “Using std::invalid_argument("text...") works fine” appears to concern code not shown here.

Comment: Throwing anything else which isn't derived from `std::exception` is usually a bad idea.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf It is now shown explicitly. It tried to say that, replacing the throw as it is written in the code for the one in the note, does not show any problem. But, you are true, it is not helping the problem. Got rid of it

Comment: I did not know that it could not convert it. Sorry for taking your time

Comment: [OT]: `s > 24 || s < 0` seems more a limitation of hour than second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are throwing a `char*` pointer but trying to catch a `std::string` object instead.  So the thrown exception is not caught.  An uncaught exception causes `terminate()` to be called, killing the process.

So, you need to either:

- throw a `std::string` to begin with:

  ```
  void Time::setSeconds(int s){
      if (s > 60 || s < 0)
          throw std::string("The value inside seconds has to be valid");
      _s = s;
  }
  ```

or

- catch a `const char*` pointer:

  ```
  catch(const char *a)
  ```

That being said, a better approach is to throw a [standard STL exception class](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/stdexcept) instead, such as [`std::out_of_range`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/out_of_range), eg:

```
#include <stdexcept>

//set the value of _s (seconds)
void Time::setSeconds(int s){
    if (s > 60 || s < 0)
        throw std::out_of_range("The value inside seconds has to be valid");
    _s = s;
}

...

try {
    Time t(12,4,-12);
    t.printStandard();
}
catch(std::exception const &a) {
    cerr << a.what();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The people in the commentary assisted me for this answer:

When using throw with an text, the compiler sees that as a `const char*`. In the code, the catch was expecting a `string const&`. The error occurs because, as said from *Cheers and hth. - Alf*

> Conversions are not considered for exception catching

Answer (score 0):

Your *catch* statement needs to specify `const char*`:

```
catch(const char* a)
{
. . .
}
```